# NodeJS Simulate Live Video Stream

Tags: node.js, express, video, live-streaming, http-live-streaming

I have a video file that I would like to start broadcasting from NodeJS, preferably through Express, at a given time. That is, if the video starts being available at timestamp t0, then if a client hits the video endpoint at time t0+60, the video playback would start at 60 seconds in.

My key requirement is that when a client connect at a given time, no more of that video be available than what would have been seen so far, so the client connecting at t0+60 would not be able to watch past the minute mark (plus some error threshold) initially, and every ~second, another second of video availability would be added, simulating a live experience synced across all clients regardless of when each loads the stream.

So far, I've tried my luck converting videos to Apple's HLS protocol (because the name sounds promising) and I was able to host the m3u8 files using Node's `hls-server` library, where the call is very straightforward:

```
import HLSServer = require('hls-server');
import http = require('http');

const source = __dirname + '/resources';

const server = http.createServer();
const hls = new HLSServer(server, {
    path: '/streams',     // Base URI to output HLS streams
    dir: source  // Directory that input files are stored
});
server.listen(8000);
```

However, it sends the entire video to the browser when asked, and appears to offer no option of forcing a start at a given frame. (I imagine forcing the start position can be done out of band by simply sending the current time to the client and then having the client do whatever is necessary with HTML and Javascript to advance to the latest position).

There are some vague approaches that I saw online that use MP4, but from what I understand, due to its compression, it is hard to know how many bytes of video data correspond to what footage duration as it may widely vary.

There are also some other tutorials which have a direct pipe from an input source such as a webcam, thereby requiring liveness, but for my comparatively simple use case where the video file is already present, I'm content with the ability to maintain a limited amount of precision, such as ±10 seconds, just as long as all clients are forced to be approximately in sync.

Thank you very much in advance, and I appreciate any pointers.